# Auto import does not use the keyword import, instead pastes the fully qualified path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm declaring a simple class that implements an interface. There is no possible name collision, the java class is not even 10 lines long

```
public class MyConfig implements IConfig {
}
```

`IConfig` is in red. Alt + Enter -> Import class produces:

```
public class MyConfig implements com.whatever.etc.IConfg {
}
```

I know that I caused this error, because I messed with optimize imports, so that there's no space between any imports except static ones, and that they are at the top. Also to never insert star imports, and a few other things. So I did this. I just don't know how and how to fix it.

I don't want to manually import things because intellij is being stupid.

Once I manually and correctly import the class, and then use "Otimise Imports", it doesn't remove the import, and fully qualify the thing like before. It just moves it to the correct lexicographical position and everything is fine. It compiles.

But again, if I delete the import, call auto import ... it pastes the fully qualified path.

WHY?!

Answer (score 0):

A restart fixed everything. Didn't even neeed to invalidate cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved by disable the fully qualified imports:
Settings --> Editor --> Code Style --> Imports tab, then
disable the check *Use fully qualified class names*